# Creating a sequence variable for crossover studies in SAS datastep

Tags: sas, datastep

I have the following dataset from a crossover design study with `participant_id`, `treatment_arm`, and `date_of_treatment` as follows:

| participant_id | treatment_arm | date_of_treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Jan 1 2022 |
| 1 | B | Jan 2 2022 |
| 1 | C | Jan 3 2022 |
| 2 | C | Jan 4 2022 |
| 2 | B | Jan 5 2022 |
| 2 | A | Jan 6 2022 |

So for `participant_id` 1, based on the order of the `date_of_treatment`, the sequence would be ABC. For `participant_id` 2, it would be CBA.

Based on the above, I want to create column `seq` as follows:

| participant_id | treatment_arm | date_of_treatment | seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Jan 1 2022 | ABC |
| 1 | B | Jan 2 2022 | ABC |
| 1 | C | Jan 3 2022 | ABC |
| 2 | C | Jan 4 2022 | CBA |
| 2 | B | Jan 5 2022 | CBA |
| 2 | A | Jan 6 2022 | CBA |

How do I go about creating the column using the 3 variables `participant_id`, `treatment_arm`, and `date_of_treatment` in datastep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a double [DoW Loop](https://sasnrd.com/sas-dow-loop-example/)

```
data want;
   do until (last.participant_id); 
      set have;   
      length seq :$3.;
      by participant_id;
      seq = cats(seq, treatment_arm);        
   end; 
   
   do until (last.participant_id);
      set have;
      by participant_id;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Remember to change the length of `seq` should there be more than 3 treatments for each participant.

```
participant_id     treatment_arm     date_of_treatment     seq    
      1                 A                01JAN2022         ABC
      1                 B                02JAN2022         ABC
      1                 C                03JAN2022         ABC
      2                 C                04JAN2022         CBA
      2                 B                05JAN2022         CBA
      2                 A                06JAN2022         CBA
```

Comment: There is no need to treat the FIRST observation in the group differently. The new variable SEQ will be reset to missing when the next data step iteration starts, which because of the DO loop is the same as when the next BY group starts.